# Дообогащения конфигурации в ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Столкнулся с проблемой дообогащения конфигурации в ExtJS.
Хочу в потомке добавить/изменить значение конфигурации, но родителю все равно приходит оригинальная конфигурация.

Пример:

```
Ext.define('test1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    config: {
        test: null,
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        console.log("constructor.test1");
        console.log(config);
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent();
    },
});  

Ext.define('test2', {
    extend: 'test1',

    config: {

    },

    constructor: function(config) {
            console.log("constructor.test2");
            this.initConfig(config);
            var innn = {
                test: 'aaaaaaaaaaaa'
            }
            var c = Ext.apply(config, innn);
            console.log(c);
            this.callParent(c);
    }
})

var exportfilterpanel = Ext.create('test2', {});
console.log(exportfilterpanel);
```

Выводит:

```
constructor.test2  
Object { test: "aaaaaaaaaaaa" }  
constructor.test1  
undefined
```

А хочется:

```
constructor.test2  
Object { test: "aaaaaaaaaaaa" }  
constructor.test1  
Object { test: "aaaaaaaaaaaa" }
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение я нашел:

```
Ext.define('test1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    config: {
        test: null,
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;
        console.log("constructor.test1");
        this.initConfig(config);
        console.log(me.config);
        this.callParent();
    },
});  

Ext.define('test2', {
    extend: 'test1',

    config: {

    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;
        console.log("constructor.test2");
        this.initConfig(config);
        console.log(me.config);
        var innn = {
            test: 'aaaaaaaaaaaa'
            }
        var c = Ext.apply(me.config, innn);
        console.log(c);
        this.callParent(c);
    }
})

var exportfilterpanel = Ext.create('test2', {'test':'init param', '1':'2'});
console.log(exportfilterpanel);
```